# cannot log into enkive mail archive

Tags: centos, email, archive

I have set up enkive on centos. I cannot seem to log into the the web interface and have followed all instructions listed [here](http://wiki.enkive.org/index.php/Installation_Instructions)

I get the following error when i use enkive username and password enkive

```
2012-08-15 12:14:35,444 [qtp218226487-29] WARN  com.linuxbox.ediscovery.authentication  - Exception in EnkiveUserFactory.authenticate()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.linuxbox.ediscovery.connector.EnkiveAuthenticator.authenticate(EnkiveAuthenticator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.AuthenticatingConnector.handshake(AuthenticatingConnector.java:403)
    at com.linuxbox.ediscovery.userfactory.EnkiveUserFactory.authenticate(EnkiveUserFactory.java:86)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.LoginController.handleRequestInternal(LoginController.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:115)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2012-08-15 12:14:35,444 [qtp218226487-29] WARN  com.linuxbox.ediscovery.authentication  - Exception in EnkiveUserFactory.authenticate()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.linuxbox.ediscovery.connector.EnkiveAuthenticator.authenticate(EnkiveAuthenticator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.AuthenticatingConnector.handshake(AuthenticatingConnector.java:403)
    at com.linuxbox.ediscovery.userfactory.EnkiveUserFactory.authenticate(EnkiveUserFactory.java:86)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.LoginController.handleRequestInternal(LoginController.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:115)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Non-ldap login fixed but using ldap I am still havin gproblems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using non-ldap i used the following settings and it worked

*jetty/webapps/enkive/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml*

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
                <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
                <user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="WEB-INF/users.properties" />
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```